# What is the best way to update a RecyclerView list, because I am getting errors in my approach?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

So I have attempted to update my `recyclerview` when a user adds themselves. Now I am trying to implement a feature where the user is able to click on a `CardView` in a `recyclerview` and the text in the `CardView` updates instantly. With my approach I have failed with `NullPointerException` because the `adapter` is apparently null. This is my source code below:

```
public class UsersList extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<UserInfo> userInfo;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    static UsersListAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userslistones, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersrecycler);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        userInfo = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
        adapter = new UsersListAdapter(userInfo);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        conditionNames = new ArrayList<>();
        populateUsersList();
        return rootView;
    }

    public void populateUsersList(){
        UsersListPopulate usersListPopulate = new UsersListPopulate(userInfo, adapter);
        usersListPopulate.execute();
    }

    public class UsersListPopulate extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ArrayList<UserInfo> list;
        UsersListAdapter adapter;

        public UsersListPopulate(ArrayList<UserInfo> list, UsersListAdapter adapter){
            this.list = list;
            this.adapter = adapter;
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String postData) {
            try {
                list.clear();
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(postData);
                for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    String forename = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("forename");
                    String surname = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("surname");
                    UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(forename, surname);
                    list.add(userInfo);
                }
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public class MarkUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String postData) {
            populateUsersList();
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting a  `NullPointerException` on the `populateUsersList()` method call in `MarkUser`.

My `stack trace`:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
  at samuel.apps.UsersList.populateUsersList(UsersList.java:100)
            at samuel.apps.UsersList.$MarkUser.onPostExecute(TabOne.java:370)
            at samuel.apps.UsersList.$MarkUser.onPostExecute(TabOne.java:345)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
```

Comment: `new UsersListPopulate(list, adapter);` should probably be  new `UsersListPopulate(userInfo, adapter);`. The stacktrace would help though

Comment: Please post a stack trace from logcat

Comment: @Karakuri, The stack trace is in the post now

Comment: Why are you resetting the adapter in onPostExecute?

Comment: Look I've tried everything and it keeps crashing, I give up

Answer (score 0):

Create a setter in your `RecyclerView.Adapter` for `DataSet` changes.

Use that along with `notifyDataSetChanged` in your `onPostExecute` of `UsersListPopulate` and see what happens.

Also, why is your `Adapter` static?